# Repair orders query in SQL Server with subselects

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if you guys know how to reduce the amount of subselects in this SQL Server Query? I think I'm using bad practices in this:

```
WITH TotalizedRepairOrders AS 
(SELECT SalesOrder,Items,DepartmentName, LastCompletedActivity,NextActivity,Plant,ParallelNextActivity  FROM OrdersSynthesis)

SELECT  Plant,
        DepartmentName,
        BlindsInQuestioning =( SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Items),0) FROM TotalizedRepairOrders WHERE NextActivity = 'NEW ORDER REVIEW' AND DepartmentName  = RO.DepartmentName),
        BlindsReadyToCross =( SELECT ISNULL( SUM(Items),0)  FROM TotalizedRepairOrders WHERE (LastCompletedActivity = 'LBM INVOICE' OR NextActivity  = 'LBM INVOICE' OR NextActivity ='PLANT ARRIVAL')  AND  DepartmentName  = RO.DepartmentName),
        BlindsPendingForShipmentCreation = ( SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(Items),0)  FROM TotalizedRepairOrders WHERE ( NextActivity  = 'RETURN SHIPMENT CREATION')  AND  DepartmentName  = RO.DepartmentName),
        PendingForInstructions = ( SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(Items),0)  FROM TotalizedRepairOrders WHERE ( ParallelNextActivity = 'INSTRUCTIONS' )  AND  DepartmentName  = RO.DepartmentName),
        PendingToBeRepaired = ( SELECT ISNULL( SUM(Items),0)  FROM TotalizedRepairOrders WHERE ( NextActivity = 'PRODUCTION' )  AND  DepartmentName  = RO.DepartmentName),
        PendingForQualityControl = ( SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(Items),0)  FROM TotalizedRepairOrders WHERE ( NextActivity = 'INSPECTION')  AND  DepartmentName  = RO.DepartmentName),
        PendingToBePacked = ( SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(Items),0)  FROM TotalizedRepairOrders WHERE ( NextActivity = 'PACKING LABEL')  AND  DepartmentName  = RO.DepartmentName)


FROM TotalizedRepairOrders RO GROUP BY  Plant ,DepartmentName
```

Comment: Have you tried to pivot the subqueries? http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/10/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler method of your query, which doesn't use a CTE and a bunch of sub-selects.

```
SELECT
    Plant
    DepartmentName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN NextActivity = 'NEW ORDER REVIEW' THEN ISNULL(Items,0) ELSE 0 END) AS BLindsInQuestion,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LastCompletedActivity = 'LBM INVOICE' OR NextActivity  = 'LBM INVOICE' OR NextActivity ='PLANT ARRIVAL' THEN ISNULL(Items,0) ELSE 0 END) as BlindsReadyToCross
    /*
    etc
    */
FROM 
    TotalizedRepairOrders
GROUP BY  Plant ,DepartmentName
```

Comment: Topsy-turvy a little. `NextActivity` is not in `GROUP BY` list and will cause compile error. `SUM(CASE WHEN...)`

Comment: This is not going to return the expected result set, you need to do the CASE within SUM, not the SUM within CASE: `SUM(CASE WHEN NextActivity = 'NEW ORDER REVIEW' THEN Items ELSE 0 END` AS BlindsInQuestioning

Comment: Yes, @IvanStarostin pointed that out I just haven't had time to fix it. This was migrated from StackOverFlow. I don't monitor CodeReview that often.